# How to change a column in pandas with a random format?

Tags: pandas, format

So I got my dataframe from a JSON file, and the date is labelled as 2000M01 for 2000 january, 2000M02 for 2000 february etc. I need to have it in a different format: 2000Jan, 2000Feb etc.-I have a different data set in this format, I could bring both of these to a third one, if that's easier. Like 2000-01 or some official date format.

My main issue is that as far as I know 2000M01 is not an official data format in any way, so I can't just convert it that way.

Any ideas how I could convert this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily feed a custom format to `pd.to_datetime`, in your case it would be `'%YM%m'`, e.g.:

```
pd.to_datetime('2000M01', format = '%YM%m')
```

Then you can convert it to any format you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the date format with the datetime module

```
def reformat_date(date_from_json):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_from_json, "%YM%m")
    return date.strftime("%Y%b")
```

As specified in [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) in strftime and strptime formats, you can deal with the unusual date formatting with %YM%m dealing with the input format with the day defaulting to the 1st, and %Y%b giving you the format you want.
Then you map the function to the pandas dataframe

```
dataframe['DATE_COLUMN'] = dataframe['OLD_DATE_COLUMN'].map(lambda date: reformat_date(date))
```